# Can we always orient a manifold to make the nowhere vanishing top form positive

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $\omega$ is a nowhere vanishing m form on a $m$- dimensional manifold $M$. Can we always orient $M$ so that $\omega$ is positive. We say a form is positive if the corresponding function in local charts is positive, i.e if $(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)$ is a chart and 
$$(\varphi_\alpha^{-1})^*\omega= F_\alpha(x_1,x_2,\cdots x_m) dx_1\wedge dx_2 \wedge ....dx_m$$ 
then $F_\alpha(x_1,x_2,\cdots x_m)$ is always positive.

This result is proposition 8.9 from the book 'Lie Groups beyond an Introduction' by Anthony W. Knapp. He just says that consider $U_\alpha$ to be connected. Then $F_\alpha$ must have a constant sign and if this sign is negative then we redefine the chart $\varphi_\alpha$ by following it with the map $(x_1,x_2,\cdots x_m)\mapsto (-x_1,x_2,\cdots x_m)$. This makes the function $F_\alpha $ positive. I don't see how the last sentence is possible.

Can someone explain the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, let us call the new coordinates $y_1,\ldots,y_m$. Then we have $$dx^1=-dy^1,$$ and $$dx^i=dy^i,\quad i=2,\ldots,m.$$ Consequently, $$dx^1\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^m=-dy^1\wedge\ldots\wedge dy^m,$$ and so, $$Fdx^1\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^m=-Fdy^1\wedge\ldots\wedge dy^m.$$

Comment: So my new $'F'$ is $'-F'$ which is positive. This almost works like magic.